# Mule Dataweave: Cannot coerce a :string to a :localdatetime

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave

Guys getting this error when trying to convert to datetime:

```
Exception while executing: 
 utcTime: (payload as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" } >> "UTC")    
              ^
 Cannot coerce a :string to a :localdatetime, caused by :Text '2018-09-25T13:09:16.258Z' could not be parsed at index 19.
```

Following is my code:

```
     <flow name="testFlow">
         <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/datetime" doc:name="HTTP"/>
         <set-payload value="#[server.dateTime.format(&quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'&quot;)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
             <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 ---
 {
 utcTime: (payload as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" } >> "UTC")    
 }

 ]]></dw:set-payload>
         </dw:transform-message>
         <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original format is different from the one you're trying to transform (missing milliseconds):

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` vs `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 2):

When setting the payload, you put in the literal character 'Z' (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'). So you can translate the literal back out:

```
(payload as :localdatetime{format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"} as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"} >> "UTC")
```

Or, you can account for the timezone:

```
<flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/datetime" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[server.dateTime.format(&quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ&quot;)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    utcTime: (payload as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" } as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"} >> "UTC")    
}

]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```